# Scrap yahoo finance "Similar to" data in Python with yfinance

Tags: python, web-scraping, yahoo-finance, yfinance

I am working on a Python project using the [yfinance](https://github.com/ranaroussi/yfinance) package, I encounter the issue of requiring "Similar to" data (s.s below)

[image: Stocks similar to MAIN stock]

## What I tried

I searched through the documentation and evaluated the data received from yf.Ticker(X) and yf.download(X), where X is the stock symbol for example "MAIN", but I found nothing.

Returned data:

[image]

## I want something like:

```py
ticker = yf.Ticker('MAIN')
similars = ticker.get_similar()
print(similars)

['PFLT','GAIN','ARCC','HRZN','HTGC']
```

Any idea how can achieve this? If it is even possibile with this package.
Should I start web scarpping this myself?

The data is essential, but I am not obligated to use Yahoo Finance. If you are aware of a package that scrapes this information from another website, I would be thankful.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I did a workaround.

I download stock data from: https://www.nasdaq.com/market-activity/stocks/screener

Head of the csv:

```
Symbol, Name, Last Sale, Net Change, % Change, Market Cap, Country, IPO Year, Volume, Sector, Industry
```

Alternately, I can get this information using yfinance, but I still need a list of every NASADQ, NYSE (and maybe other) listed stocks.

```py
import pandas as pd

def similar_stocks(ticker): 
    # Static data
    nasdaq_data = pd.read_csv("nasdaq_screener.csv")
    ticker_row = nasdaq_data.loc[nasdaq_data['Symbol'] == ticker]  # ticker_row: {DataFrame } Symbol, Name ... Industry

    # Filter by sector
    ticker_sector = ticker_row['Sector'].values[0]  # Finance
    filter_condition = nasdaq_data['Sector'] == ticker_sector
    filtered_data = nasdaq_data[filter_condition]  # By Finance

    market_cap = ticker_row['Market Cap'].values[0]
    treshold = 0.15 * market_cap  # 15% of the company value
    min_limit = str(market_cap - treshold)
    max_limit = str(market_cap + treshold)

    # Filter by market cap
    filtered_data = filtered_data[filtered_data['Symbol'] != ticker]
    filtered_data = filtered_data.query(min_limit + ' < `Market Cap` < ' + max_limit)

    return filtered_data.Symbol.tolist()  # ['ABCB', 'APAM', ... 'UTF', 'WSFS']
```

I filtered the original data by industry and comparable market capitalizations.